# Is it possible to have AM2+ mobo with 790fx chipset and have DDR3 Ram support?

Tags: motherboard, ddr3, am2+

Is it possible to have AMD AM2+ mobo with 790fx chipset and still have DDR3 Ram support? Also do you think DDR3 is worth it? I like [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131361&cm_re=790fx-_-13-131-361-_-Product) but it doesnt have DDR3 support :(

Comment: I assume you meant the 790fx in my answer. Please let me know if you meant a different one.

Comment: Ya really sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: AM2+ processors only support DDR2, so any board with that socket will have DDR2 to maintain compatibility. To have DDR3 support, you would need a AM3 motherboard.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_AM2%2B

> AMD confirmed that there is an upgrade path from Socket AM2+ to AM3:
>
> AM3 processors work on AM2+ motherboards due to the presence of both the DDR2 and DDR3 memory controller
> AM2+ processors do not work on AM3 motherboards due to the lack of the DDR3 memory controller
> The pin configuration of the AM2+ socket (940 pins)[2] is mechanically different from the AM3 socket (938 pins)[2]

It looks like the 790fx chipset only support DDR2 also. I assume you mean the 790 if you mention a fx chipset?

http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/chipsets/7-series-discrete/Pages/amd-790fx-chipset.aspx

The only 740 is the 740g chipset: http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/chipsets/7-series-integrated/Pages/amd-740g-chipset.aspx

DDR3 is the new standard for RAM. DDR2 prices may fall and will eventualy rise some as it is phased out over the coming years.  Most of the small home servers and small notebooks still use it though. If you are upgrading a current system and using an older processor and parts, then DDR2 is your only path.  If you are building a new machine, I would go DDR3.  It is getting cheaper by the day, faster in many aspects, and most newer boards come with it.

If your trying to build a super cheap system, then DDR2 might be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

What CPU are you going to use? Chances are it is AM2 or AM2+ and only supports DDR2 (memory controller is integrated in the CPU) making this question moot.

[AM+ in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_AM2%2B).